# Reactives in Loops

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to create various tabs and take dates as inputs in those tabs, depending on these dates, I'll try to point to a location where a list of files will be given as option to select one and display. These can be different on different tabs, so I have following so far -

**ui part**

```
Some_List <- list("AGG", "CMP1", "CMP2")
Some_Long_List <- list("Aggregated Things", "Component 1", "Component 2")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
do.call(sidebarMenu, c(lapply(1:length(Some_List), function(i) {
menuItem(Some_Long_List[i], tabName = paste0(Some_List[i],"_tab"))
}))))

uibody <- dashboardBody(
do.call(tabItems, c(lapply(1:length(Some_List), function(i) {
tabItem(tabName = paste0(Some_List[i],"_tab"), h2(Some_Long_List[i]),
fluidPage(fluidRow(column(3,
dateInput(paste0("ME_DATE_output_",Some_List[i]),label=h2("Select a Date"), value="2020-05-29"))
,column(9,column(verbatimTextOutput(paste0("file_path_",Some_List[i])),width=12),hr(),
    selectInput(paste0('select_file_',Some_List[i]),'Select a File to display', choices=NULL),hr(),
    column(dataTableOutput(paste0('selected_table_',Some_List[i])),width=12)))))
}))))

ui = dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Results"), sidebar, uibody)
```

**server part**

```
server = function(input, output, session) { 
# Location for Source Inputs
Some_dir <- "K:/Outputs"

ME_DATE_GUI <- reactive({lapply(1:length(Some_List), function(k) input[[paste0("ME_DATE_output_",Some_List[k])]])})
Some_loc <- reactive({lapply(1:length(Some_List), function(k)
    file.path(paste0(Some_dir,format(input[[paste0("ME_DATE_output_",Some_List[k])]],"%m"),". ",format(input[[paste0("ME_DATE_output_",Some_List[k])]], "%B"), " ",format(input[[paste0("ME_DATE_output_",Some_List[k])]],"%Y"),"/",sep=""))
)})

# Files Path
lapply(1:length(Some_List), function(k) output[[paste0("file_path_",Some_List[k])]] <- renderPrint({ req(Some_loc()[[k]]) }))

# Updated Files list  
Updated_files_list <-  reactive({  
req(Some_loc())
lf_some <- list.files(Some_loc()[[1]],full.names = TRUE )
names(lf_some) <- basename(lf_some)
lf_some
})

# Fetch selection of file
lapply(1:length(Some_List), function(k)
observeEvent(Updated_files_list(), {    
updateSelectInput(session, paste0("select_file_",Some_List[k]), choices=Updated_files_list())
}))

# Display Selected file
lapply(1:length(Some_List), function(k)
output[[paste0("selected_table_",Some_List[k])]] <- renderDataTable({
req(input[[paste0("select_file_", Some_List[k])]])
read.csv(input[[paste0("select_file_", Some_List[k])]], header=T)
}))

}
```

The above works in a way that I can make changes to first tab now and the list for selection and view is available to all the tabs without any error. The problem is any changes in date in other tabs isn't updating the list, because I have used [[1]] in Updated_files_list function and I can't get to use k in there and be able to successfully use k from later lapply while fetching this list.
Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: I have not checked everything. I see that in some places you have to use `[[k]]` instead of `[k]`. For example `lf_some[[k]] <- list.files(......)`. To set a name to the k-th element you have to do `names(lf_some)[k] <- ......`. But `basename(lf_some[[k]])` will return a vector if there are several files in `lf_some[[k]]`, and you cannot use a vector as a name.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent, I have updated the q on what's working and what's remaining. Thanks for your help.